# article slider does not work twice on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have in my website a slider with articles. He has 9 cells.
But I need 9 more cells, and I want them below the first slide. But when I duplicate on index the second slider doesn't work.

```
  <section class="slider">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content slider-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG1.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Caixa Cartão Bolo Rei 28x28x7,5</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,53€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG2.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Guardanapo Natal PPP 40x40 Nova Era 24 maços </h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">19,93€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG3.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Saco plástico alça Natal medida 50x55</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">2,50€* / Kg</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG4.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Saqueta Bolo Rei 26+8x42 c/ 500 sacos</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,11€* / Saco</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG5.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Lava Loiça Profissional Fairy 5 Lts Ultra</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">8,99€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG6.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Esfregão Saponificado Favir c/6 Unds</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,49€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG8.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Bloco Sanitário Senses 60 Grs</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,48€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG7.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Toalha de mão 21x22 Amoos c/2800 fls</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">10,46€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
          <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG9.png" alt="" class="card-img">
          <h1 class="card-title">Tira Nódoas Fun Clorossan Roupa Branca/cor 800grs</h1>
          <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-price">10,46€* / caixa</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    

    <span class="arrow left">&#129120;</span>
    <span class="arrow right">&#129122;</span>
  </section>

  <script src="js/scriptDestaques.js"></script>
```

This is the index, and when I do copy paste this section the second slider doesn't work.

```
:root {
  --primary: #ffffff;
  /* --primary: #fff; */
  --secondary: #13533A;
  --bg: #0e1523;
  /* --bg: #f5f5f5; */
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  /*background-color: var(--bg);*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider {
  /*background-color: var(--bg);*/
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 7rem auto;
  display: flex;
  /*display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  grid-gap: 2rem;*/

 /* font: normal 1rem sans-serif;*/
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;

  min-width: 17rem;
  height: 23rem;
  background-color:var(--primary);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: .1rem solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem .6rem #0003;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
      min-width: 21rem;
  }
}

.card:not(:first-child){
  margin-left: 2rem;
  border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
}

.card:first-child{
  margin-left: .4rem;
  border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
}

.card:hover {
  border: .2rem solid var(--secondary);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card .card-top-img{
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card::before, .card::after {
  position: absolute;
 /* content: "";
  background-color: var(--secondary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;*/
  z-index: 100;
}

.card::before {
  top: -6%;
  right: -6%;
  width: 9rem;
  height: 9rem;
}

.card::after {
  bottom: -6%;
  left: -6%;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.card:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.8);
}

.card:hover::after {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.card-content {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 200;
}

.card-content img {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card-img, 
.card-title {
  transform: translateY(4rem);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #13533A;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-img {
  width: auto;
  height: 9.5rem;
}

.card-title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition-delay: .1s;
  color: #13533A;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card-body, 
.card-footer {
  transform: translateY(10rem);
  padding: 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-body {
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.card:hover .card-img,
.card:hover .card-title,
.card:hover .card-body,
.card:hover .card-footer {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card-footer {
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

.button-slider {
  width: max-content;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.slider-footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card-body p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #111;
}




.card-price {
  font: bolder 1.5rem sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: unset;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: var(--secondary);
}

.btn-border {
  border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
}

.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50%; */
  align-self: center;
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); */

  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;

  border-radius: 50%;
  font: 800 1.5rem sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
  user-select: none;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 300;
}

.arrow:active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.left{
  left: 1rem;
}

.right{
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const right_arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow.right');
const left_arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow.left');

let left = 0;
let card_size = 25.4;
let total_card_size = cards.length * card_size - card_size * 4;

if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches){
    card_size = 52;
    total_card_size = cards.length * card_size - card_size * 2;
}

if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 568px)').matches){
    card_size = 52;
    total_card_size = cards.length * card_size - card_size * 2;
}

left_arrow.onclick = () => {
    left -= card_size;

    if(left <= 0) left = 0;
    moveCards(left);
    checkArrowVisibility(left);
}

left_arrow.style.opacity = '0';


right_arrow.onclick = () => {
    left += card_size;

    if(left >= total_card_size) left = total_card_size;
    moveCards(left);
    checkArrowVisibility(left);
}

function moveCards(left) {
    for(card of cards) {
        card.style.left = -left + "%";
    }
}


function checkArrowVisibility(pos){
    if(pos == 0 ) {
        left_arrow.style.opacity = '0';
    }else {
        left_arrow.style.opacity = '1';
    }
    if(pos >= total_card_size ) {
        right_arrow.style.opacity = '0';
    }else {
        right_arrow.style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

And this is JavaScript.

I have other small thing's on bootstrap too.

I try to copy paste the code on index.
I was expecting the code duplicate and work fine.

Comment: `querySelector` retrieves only the first element that meets the condition,
Therefore the following buttons are not applicable.

Comment: @DucHo   So I try now to put querySelectorAll, but this broke everything. The first element doesn't work and the second no working too. So I try to create new classes and a new .JS file but that does not work too. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query in element, so group the statements and run it on each `section`.

Refe:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('section.slider').forEach(i => {
        const cards = i.querySelectorAll('.card');
        const right_arrow = i.querySelector('.arrow.right');
        const left_arrow = i.querySelector('.arrow.left');


        const moveCards = function (left) {
            for (card of cards) {
                card.style.left = -left + "%";
            }
        }

        const checkArrowVisibility = function (pos) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                left_arrow.style.opacity = '0';
            } else {
                left_arrow.style.opacity = '1';
            }
            if (pos >= total_card_size) {
                right_arrow.style.opacity = '0';
            } else {
                right_arrow.style.opacity = '1';
            }
        }

        let left = 0;
        let card_size = 25.4;
        let total_card_size = cards.length * card_size - card_size * 4;

        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
            card_size = 52;
            total_card_size = cards.length * card_size - card_size * 2;
        }

        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 568px)').matches) {
            card_size = 52;
            total_card_size = cards.length * card_size - card_size * 2;
        }

        left_arrow.onclick = () => {
            left -= card_size;

            if (left <= 0) left = 0;
            moveCards(left);
            checkArrowVisibility(left);
        }

        left_arrow.style.opacity = '0';


        right_arrow.onclick = () => {
            left += card_size;

            if (left >= total_card_size) left = total_card_size;
            moveCards(left);
            checkArrowVisibility(left);
        }
    })
```

```css
:root {
    --primary: #ffffff;
    /* --primary: #fff; */
    --secondary: #13533A;
    --bg: #0e1523;
    /* --bg: #f5f5f5; */
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body{
    /*background-color: var(--bg);*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .slider {
    /*background-color: var(--bg);*/
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 7rem auto;
    display: flex;
    /*display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    place-items: center;
    grid-gap: 2rem;*/
  
   /* font: normal 1rem sans-serif;*/
  }
  
  .card {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
  
    min-width: 17rem;
    height: 23rem;
    background-color:var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border: .1rem solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 .2rem .6rem #0003;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .card {
        min-width: 21rem;
    }
  }
  
  .card:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 2rem;
    border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
  }
  
  .card:first-child{
    margin-left: .4rem;
    border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    border: .2rem solid var(--secondary);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  
  .card .card-top-img{
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  
  .card::before, .card::after {
    position: absolute;
   /* content: "";
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;*/
    z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .card::before {
    top: -6%;
    right: -6%;
    width: 9rem;
    height: 9rem;
  }
  
  .card::after {
    bottom: -6%;
    left: -6%;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
  }
  
  .card:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  
  .card:hover::after {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 200;
  }
  
  .card-content img {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  
  .card-img, 
  .card-title {
    transform: translateY(4rem);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    color: #13533A;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .card-img {
    width: auto;
    height: 9.5rem;
  }
  
  .card-title {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition-delay: .1s;
    color: #13533A;
      font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .card-body, 
  .card-footer {
    transform: translateY(10rem);
    padding: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .card-body {
    width: 100%;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  
    transition-delay: .2s;
  }
  
  .card:hover .card-img,
  .card:hover .card-title,
  .card:hover .card-body,
  .card:hover .card-footer {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .card-footer {
    transition-delay: .3s;
  }
  
  .button-slider {
    width: max-content;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  
  .slider-footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  
  .card-body p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #111;
  }
  
  
  
  
  .card-price {
    font: bolder 1.5rem sans-serif;
  }
  
  .btn {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    background-color: unset;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .btn-success {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
  }
  
  .btn-border {
    border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
  }
  
  .arrow{
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    align-self: center;
    /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
  
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
  
    border-radius: 50%;
    font: 800 1.5rem sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3rem;
    user-select: none;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 300;
  }
  
  .arrow:active {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .left{
    left: 1rem;
  }
  
  .right{
    right: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
 <section class="slider">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content slider-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG1.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Caixa Cartão Bolo Rei 28x28x7,5</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,53€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG2.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Guardanapo Natal PPP 40x40 Nova Era 24 maços </h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">19,93€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG3.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Saco plástico alça Natal medida 50x55</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">2,50€* / Kg</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG4.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Saqueta Bolo Rei 26+8x42 c/ 500 sacos</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,11€* / Saco</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG5.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Lava Loiça Profissional Fairy 5 Lts Ultra</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">8,99€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG6.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Esfregão Saponificado Favir c/6 Unds</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,49€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG8.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Bloco Sanitário Senses 60 Grs</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,48€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG7.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Toalha de mão 21x22 Amoos c/2800 fls</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">10,46€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
          <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG9.png" alt="" class="card-img">
          <h1 class="card-title">Tira Nódoas Fun Clorossan Roupa Branca/cor 800grs</h1>
          <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-price">10,46€* / caixa</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    

    <span class="arrow left">&#129120;</span>
    <span class="arrow right">&#129122;</span>
  </section>
 <section class="slider">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content slider-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG1.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Caixa Cartão Bolo Rei 28x28x7,5</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,53€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG2.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Guardanapo Natal PPP 40x40 Nova Era 24 maços </h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">19,93€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG3.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Saco plástico alça Natal medida 50x55</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">2,50€* / Kg</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG4.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Saqueta Bolo Rei 26+8x42 c/ 500 sacos</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,11€* / Saco</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG5.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Lava Loiça Profissional Fairy 5 Lts Ultra</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">8,99€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG6.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Esfregão Saponificado Favir c/6 Unds</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,49€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG8.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Bloco Sanitário Senses 60 Grs</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">0,48€* / uni</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG7.png" alt="" class="card-img">
            <h1 class="card-title">Toalha de mão 21x22 Amoos c/2800 fls</h1>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-price">10,46€* / caixa</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
              <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
          <img src="images/FotosDestaque/IMG9.png" alt="" class="card-img">
          <h1 class="card-title">Tira Nódoas Fun Clorossan Roupa Branca/cor 800grs</h1>
          <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-price">10,46€* / caixa</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer slider-footer">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='catalogo.php'" class="btn btn-success button-slider">Comprar</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    

    <span class="arrow left">&#129120;</span>
    <span class="arrow right">&#129122;</span>
  </section>

  <script src="js/scriptDestaques.js"></script>
```

That's not necessarily the best way, but it ensures your current source can run.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpufull. Now it works fine. Thanks!